# Error when adding Logback to classpath

Tags: logback

Whenever I try to run setClasspath.sh in logback-examples, I get an error.
My logback setClasspath.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

##
# This script will add logback jars to your classpath.
##

LB_HOME=/home/darryl/logback

CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LB_HOME}/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar"
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LB_HOME}/logback-core-1.1.1.jar"
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LB_HOME}/logback-examples/logback-examples-1.1.1.jar"
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${LB_HOME}/logback-examples/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar"

export CLASSPATH

echo $CLASSPATH
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
: not foundath.sh: 2: ./setClasspath.sh: 
: not foundath.sh: 6: ./setClasspath.sh: 
: not foundath.sh: 8: ./setClasspath.sh: 
: not foundath.sh: 13: ./setClasspath.sh: 
: bad variable name14: export: CLASSPATH
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Your issue is too specific. You should probably give more details. Considering the error messages, I'd say there's something wrong about your current terminal (error messages overwritten). Do you know on which shell /bin/sh is pointing?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and extracted latest logback version (logback-1.1.1.tar.bz2). This archive contains a logback-examples/setClasspath.sh script but this script is not executable by default. Actually, it's not stored with executable permissions in tar archive. I gave it executable permissions using:

```
chmod +x setClasspath.sh
```

I ran it and it complains about a carriage return at the end of line. (odd ^M character)
Thus, this file uses wrong new line formats (windows format \r\n and not unix format: \n).
You should just convert this file to unix format and try to run it again. Install dos2unix utility on your system. For your information, on debian or ubuntu, you can run this as root

```
apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then, as standard user, convert the file from dos format to unix/linux format:

```
dos2unix setClasspath.sh
```

You should probably notify logback guys about this small issue.